# False 'Corollary' to the Universal Coefficient Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've been practicing doing computations with the Universal Coefficient Theorem recently, and I came upon the following claim.

> Suppose $f,g: X \to Y$ are maps such that $f_* = g_* : H_*(X) \to H_*(Y)$. There are cases in the literature of the Universal Coeffecient Theorem implying as a corollary that $f_* = g_*$ as maps $H_*(X;G) \to H_*(Y;G)$ for $\textit{any}$ group $G$, but this is false.

Can anyone help me find such an example? I've thrown all the familiar examples I can think of at it this afternoon and have not yet found one. If the computation to prove that a particular example works is hard, just the example itself suffices, I'll try the calculation myself.

Comment: Well, if you take, say, $\mathbb{R}P^2$, then $H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2) = 0$ but $H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{Z}/2) = \mathbb{Z}/2$. So you can take $f$ to be the identity $\mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ and $g$ to be a constant map.

Comment: It seems that in that example, $f$ and $g$ do not induce the same maps on integer homology. The first homology of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but $g$ would induce the $0$ map on homology, no?

Comment: I took your question to be asking about a single degree, not on all degrees.

Comment: Well, I have quoted the statement more or less as I saw it - I've left all the notation alone but changed some of the words around because I don't have the reference on hand and just copied from my notebook. In a single degree, I agree this example works. My interpretation was that $f$ and $g$ should do the same thing on all homology groups, but after changing coefficients, at least one group is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}P^2 \to S^2$ the map which collapses $\mathbb{R}P^1$ to a point (looking at $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with the standard inductive CW-complex structure of adjoining the previous one), and $g: \mathbb{R}P^2 \to S^2$ a constant map. Since 
$$H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \quad H_1(S^2;\mathbb{Z})=0$$
and 
$$H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})=0, \quad H_2(S^2;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z},$$
we have that $f_*=0=g_*$. However, $f_*:H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to H_2(S^2,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism, which can be seen from computing the induced map via cellular homology with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. For more details, there is a discussion of this map in the chapter of the universal coefficients theorem in Bredon.